# toast image title onclick

Tags: java, android, onclick, toast

I have this code on an Recycleview image gallery. 
I want to toast the title of each image.
How can i do so ?

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImage_title());
    viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImage_ID()));
    viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is fairly simple... you can get the name with this `galleryList.get(i).getImage_title()` and just toast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(context,galleryList.get(i).getImage_title(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```